# mysql join question, joining newest record in a one to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, mysql, join

I have a simple (hopefully) SQL question for you, any help would be much, much appreciated :).

I have two tables which I would like to join.

One Is Users, lets say it's called users

One is a kind of history of that user, lets say its called users_history.

The relationship of these two is a one **users** to many **users_history** relationship.

What I'd like to do is a query which joins the tables and joins the newest record in users_history onto each user.

Lets say the tables are like this, I'm simplifying for conciseness.

**users**

- id
- name

**users_history**

- id
- user_id
- date

The date is formatted YYYYMMDD.

The end result is I'd like to be able to pull out all of the users who don't have a users_history record for today, for example today is 20101021.

Any help would be very gratefully received! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(users_history.date), users.name FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_history ON users.id = users_history.user_id
GROUP BY users_history.user_id
HAVING MAX(users_history.date) < CURDATE()
```

If you dont want users who doesnt have eny users_history records in the resultset, change the "LEFT JOIN" to a "JOIN"

Comment: If there is no Users_history record for a user then MAX(users_history.date) will be NULL and the HAVING clause will fail.  Users with no Users_history record satisfy the requirements and should be selected.

Comment: +1 COALESCEing the MAX date with a date before today in the HAVING clause should take care of the issue Paul mentions in his first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If all you really want is finding the users without a `user_history` entry for today, you can use a subquery like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users_history WHERE user_id = users.id AND `date` = DATE(NOW()));
```

IMHO, this is more readable than a join and some filtering in your host language.

edit: Judging from your date format description, you probably use a `varchar`column to store the date. In that case, replace `DATE(NOW())` with the appropriate string representation for "today" - though I'd recommend changing the column type to a [date/time type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Answer (score 1):

pull out all of the users who don't have a users_history record for today, for example today is 20101021.

```
select
 u.*
from
 users u
left outer join users_history uh on 
  u.id = uh.user_id and uh.history_date = curdate()
where
 uh.user_id is null;
```